# Rails - simple_form_for on a triple nested route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know, triple nesting is looked down upon but I'm trying to figure out how to properly create this form and I'm stuck. I have a model Topic which has_many Questions which has_many Citations. I am getting an error that says there are no route matches.

There routing is set up as follows:

```
resources :topics do
  resources :questions do  
    resources :citations
  end
end
```

All models are properly set up with has_many/belongs_to associations. And everything works properly between Topic and Question.

I use the following to (attempt to) create a new Citation:

```
<%= link_to "Add a citation", new_topic_question_citation_path(@topic, @question.id) %>
```

and then build a form with:

```
<%= simple_form_for @citation, url: topic_question_citation_path(@topic.id, @question.id) do |f| ... %>
```

but I get hit with the following error on the form:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :topic_id=>6, :controller=>"citations", 
:question_id=>84}, missing required keys: [:id]
```

On the same page, it shows:

```
Request
Parameters: 
{"topic_id"=>"topic1", "question_id"=>"84"}
```

For my citation_controller, I have:

```
class CitationsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @question = @topic.questions.find(params[:question_id])
    @citation = @question.citations.new(citation_params)
    @citation.user = current_user
    if @citation.save!
      flash[:notice] = "Your submission has been accepted and will be reviewed by a moderator."
      redirect_to topic_question_path(@topic, @question.id)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def new
    @citation = Citation.new
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
  end  

  def index
    @citations = Citation.all
  end

  def show
    authorize! :read, @citation
  end



  ...

end
```

This format works for all my other models that are nested two deep. What is going wrong here and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> No route matches {:action=>"show", :topic_id=>6,
>   :controller=>"citations",  :question_id=>84}, missing required keys:
>   [:id]

The ***path helper*** for creating `citations` should be `topic_question_citations_path` not `topic_question_citation_path`. Notice the change `citations` instead of `citation`.

Make this change to fix the error

```
<%= simple_form_for @citation, url: topic_question_citations_path(@topic.id, @question.id) do |f| ... %>
```

**OR**

It can be simply written as

```
<%= simple_form_for [@topic, @question, @citation] do |f| %>
```

**Hint:**

Always run `rake routes` to see the ***available path helpers***. Each path helper will be mapped to certain `controller#action`. So you can fix such errors by comparing  the respected available path helper with the one you are using.